# can't read many files at once using python

Tags: python

The code is like this below i tried

```
import os
for path,dirs,files in os.walk("C:/Users/yeshiwas/Desktop/IR_ass/"):
    for f in files:
        filename=os.path.join(path,f)
        with open(filename,"r") as myfile:
            print(filename)
            print(myfile.read())
            myfile.close()
```

Showing the error:

```
UnicodeDecodeError: 'charmap' codec can't decode byte 0x90 in position 2748: character maps to <undefined>
```

Comment: You are reading a text file.  In whatever file you're reading, the character at position 2748 is the byte 0x90, which is not valid in the standard UTF-8 encoding.   Can you open the file in a text editor and find out what is there?  The error message is literally telling you the problem.

Comment: check [codecs.open](https://docs.python.org/3/library/codecs.html#codecs.open)